# How to match the complete getText in a tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html part of the form

```
html_part = """<b>Name <font style="white-space:nowrap">Classification</font> Class A Sector B Hollow C </b>"""
```

I want to use BeautifulSoup to match this

```
partSoup = BeautifulSoup(html_part)
partSoup.getText() gives me 

'Name Classification Class A Sector B Hollow C '
```

I want to use a regular expression to match this

But since there is an embeded tag, the simple find_all using text does not match the whole string

So

```
partSoup.findAll(text=re.compile("^Name.*"))
```

Gives me

```
['Name ']
```

I want to do something like

```
partSoup.findAll(where get text = re.compile("^Name.*Hollow.*"))
```

and get the complete tag as a result.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Do you search for bs4 solution only?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. It has to be a custom function:

```
def isMatchingText(tag):
    matchedResult = None
    matchedResult = re.search(searchPattern,tag.getText())
    if matchedResult is None:
        return False
    return True

partSoup.findAll(isMatchingText)
```

Please note that this is different from

```
partSoup.findAll(text=re.sub(searchPattern))
```

Which was what I was orignally trying with. The differece is that it does not concatinate child tag texts into a complete text blob - which is what I was looking for.